# how to import pandas in ipython notebook on ubuntu

Tags: python, pandas, ipython

I am trying to import pandas in ipython notebook but that time getting below error:

In [2]: import pandas as pd

---

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 import pandas as pd

ImportError: No module named 'pandas'

Comment: Have you tried installing pandas for the same interpreter you're using?

Answer (score 1):

Okay this is most definitely an error which appears when you don't have a particular module installed in your Ipython Environment. In your case, it is the 'pandas' module you are trying to import:

```
import pandas as pd
```

This won't work before you have your pandas module installed in your development environment.

You can learn how to install pandas from their official website : http://pandas.pydata.org/.

> Best way to get pandas is to install via conda Builds for osx-64,linux-64,linux-32,win-64,win-32 for Python 2.7, Python 3.4, and Python 3.5 are all available.
>
> > conda install pandas

The above command will work only if you are working with the conda environment.

You can also install pandas using the pip module. Type :

```
pip install pandas
import pandas as pd
```

This should most definitely solve your problem. Detailed installation instructions can be found on :
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/install.html